# Performance problems in Compose application with Room

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I am building an application which implements chatting. I started noticing frame drops when I navigate from Chats screen to a specific Chat screen, which is noticeable because default `NavHost` animation is skipped. All testing was performed on `release` build with minification enabled.

Data for messages comes from a local DB through Room, as it is my source of truth, but UI for messages is also non-trivial, so there I had my candidates for optimization.

I decided to run a series of macrobenchmarks to discover a direction to look at. My benchmark is implemented like this:

```kotlin
@Test
fun navigateToChat() = benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
    packageName = "my.package",
    metrics = listOf(FrameTimingMetric()),
    iterations = 50,
    startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
    compilationMode = CompilationMode.Ignore()
) {
    pressHome()
    startActivityAndWait()
    device.waitForIdle()
    val chatItem = device.findObject(By.text("Some guy's name"))
    chatItem.click()
    device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Some message text")), 500)
}
```

And I got the following results for the base case:

```
DB read, with UI (control, vector chat background):
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   21.6,   P90  136.4,   P95  161.8,   P99  249.3
frameOverrunMs       P50   44.8,   P90  183.7,   P95  238.3,   P99  383.6
```

Considering there are only 12 messages in this chat and my device is a Pixel 7a, this is absolutely horrific.

For each of the next benchmarks I changed DB interaction and/or UI rendering to see what causes such a load:

```
DB read, with UI (no chat BG):
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   26.4,   P90  139.9,   P95  161.0,   P99  192.3
frameOverrunMs       P50   54.3,   P90  177.9,   P95  219.0,   P99  280.6

DB read, with UI (raster chat BG):
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   31.4,   P90  155.3,   P95  169.3,   P99  262.2
frameOverrunMs       P50   64.4,   P90  183.4,   P95  235.4,   P99  307.8

DB read, with UI (raster chat BG, no shadow on a custom shape):
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   17.5,   P90   95.8,   P95  137.9,   P99  166.4
frameOverrunMs       P50   14.5,   P90  146.9,   P95  169.5,   P99  200.7

DB read, no UI:
frameDurationCpuMs   P50    6.3,   P90   45.5,   P95   81.9,   P99  121.3
frameOverrunMs       P50   -1.8,   P90   71.7,   P95  106.3,   P99  157.1

DB read, trivial UI (Text instead of MessageBubble):
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   17.7,   P90   97.6,   P95  146.2,   P99  239.6
frameOverrunMs       P50   26.2,   P90  162.9,   P95  217.7,   P99  252.9

No DB read, UI provided with the same data by hand:
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   14.7,   P90  133.2,   P95  211.1,   P99  277.6
frameOverrunMs       P50   20.1,   P90  178.5,   P95  231.0,   P99  266.4

No DB read, trivial UI:
frameDurationCpuMs   P50   9.8,   P90     79.3,   P95    127.2,   P99    281.5
frameOverrunMs       P50   8.7,   P90    124.4,   P95    215.1,   P99    288.8
```

And results are inconclusive, indicating that both DB query and UI are inefficient. None of UI optimizations or `Dispatchers` juggling I tried worked, so I would really appreciate some guidance.

#### Database query

The query I make to fetch chat info is this:

```
@Transaction
@Query("""
    SELECT * FROM ChatEntity c
    JOIN ChatMessageEntity m ON c.id = m.chatId
    WHERE c.id = :id
    ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC
    LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
""")
fun getChat(
    id: Int,
    limit: Int,
    offset: Int
): Flow<Map<ChatWithParticipants, List<ChatMessageEntity>>>
```

Where `ChatWithParticipants` is:

```
data class ChatWithParticipants(
    @Embedded
    val chatEntity: ChatEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = ParticipantInChatCrossRef::class,
            parentColumn = "chatId",
            entityColumn = "participantId"
        )
    )
    val participants: List<ChatParticipantEntity>
)
```

All foreign keys are covered by indices.

Then, through a Repository, data ends up in a `ViewModel`:

```
val chatState = repo.getChat(chatId, page = 0, pageSize = 15)
    .mapLatest {
        it.toChatState()
    }
    .stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(1000),
        null
    )
```

Where `toChatState()` is:

```
fun Map<ChatWithParticipants, List<ChatMessageEntity>>.toChatState(): ChatState {
    val chat = keys.first()
    val messages = entries.firstOrNull()?.value ?: emptyList()

    return ChatState(
        id = chat.chatEntity.id,
        type = chat.chatEntity.type,
        createdAt = chat.chatEntity.createdAt,
        participants = chat.participants.map { it.toParticipant() },
        messages = messages.map { message ->
            message.toMessage(
                sender = chat.participants.find { it.id == message.senderId }!!
                    .toParticipant(),
                contents = emptyList()
            )
        },
        owner = chat.participants.first().toParticipant(),
        participantsLimit = chat.chatEntity.participantsLimit,
        participantsCount = chat.chatEntity.participantsCount,
        unreadMessagesCount = chat.chatEntity.unreadCount
    )
}
```

None of this seems particularly hard on the CPU, but benchmarks speak the opposite.

#### UI

Leaving out everything unimportant, this is my Chat screen:

```
@Composable
fun Chat(
    viewModel: ChatViewModel
) {
    val chatState by viewModel.chatState.collectAsState()
    val currentUserId by viewModel.currentUserId.collectAsState()

    chatState?.let {
        ChatContent(
            chatState = it,
            currentUserId = currentUserId
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ChatContent(
    chatState: ChatState,
    currentUserId: Int?
) {
    val owner = chatState.owner ?: return
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lastSeen = remember(chatState.owner) {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) "kk:mm"
            else "hh:mm a"
        ).format(owner.lastOnline)
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            // Avatar with Coil, name, last seen
        },
        content = {
            val resources = LocalContext.current.resources

            val brush = remember {
                val pattern = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                    resources,
                    R.drawable.chat_pattern,
                    null
                )!!.toBitmap().asImageBitmap()

                ShaderBrush(
                    ImageShader(
                        image = pattern,
                        tileModeX = TileMode.Repeated,
                        tileModeY = TileMode.Repeated
                    )
                )
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(it)
                    .background(brush)
            ) {

                LazyColumn(/*...*/) {
                    itemsIndexed(
                        items = chatState.messages,
                        key = { _, it -> it.id }
                    ) { index, it ->
                        val iPreviousMessageFromOther = remember {
                            chatState.messages.getOrNull(index - 1)
                                ?.sender?.id != it.sender.id
                        }
                        val isNextMessageFromOther = remember {
                            chatState.messages.getOrNull(index + 1)
                                ?.sender?.id != it.sender.id
                        }
                        val isCurrentUserAuthor = remember {
                            it.sender.id == currentUserId
                        }
                        MessageBubble(
                            chatMessage = it,
                            isCurrentUserAuthor = isCurrentUserAuthor,
                            shouldShowTail = iPreviousMessageFromOther
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            // ...
        }
    )
}
```

`MessageBubble` seems like the most calculation-heavy UI component to me. I think so because of multiple things:

- A custom `MessageBubbleShape` which adds a "tail" to the shape.
- A custom layout to position message text and its status (sent at, has been read, has been edited), which requires text measuring via a `TextMeasurer`.

```
fun MessageBubble(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    chatMessage: ChatMessage,
    isCurrentUserAuthor: Boolean,
    shouldShowTail: Boolean
) {
    val largeShape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large
    val shape = remember(shouldShowTail) {
        if (shouldShowTail) LargeMessageBubbleShape
        else largeShape
    }

    val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val shouldRotate = remember(layoutDirection, isCurrentUserAuthor) {
        layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr && !isCurrentUserAuthor
                || layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Rtl && isCurrentUserAuthor
    }
    val messageTime = remember {
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)) "kk:mm"
            else "hh:mm a"
        ).format(chatMessage.createdAt)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            // bla bla
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer {
                    if (shouldRotate) {
                        rotationY = 180f
                    }
                }
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 1.dp,
                    shape = shape
                )
                .background(
                    color = // bla,
                    shape = shape
                ) //.bla(bla)

        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        if (shouldRotate) {
                            rotationY = 180f
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

                val messageTextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
                val density = LocalDensity.current

                Layout(
                    content = {
                        Text(
                            text = chatMessage.text,
                            style = messageTextStyle
                        )

                        Row(
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = messageTime,
                                // ...
                            )
                            if (isCurrentUserAuthor) {
                                Icon(
                                    // ...
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
                        val messageMeasurement = textMeasurer.measure(
                            text = chatMessage.text,
                            constraints = constraints,
                            style = messageTextStyle
                        )

                        // A bunch of calculations which don't seem important because 
                        // in spite of them the list of bubbles scrolls smoothly.

                        layout(
                            width = layoutWidth,
                            height = layoutHeight
                        ) {
                            text.placeRelative(0, 0)
                            if (timeHasSpaceHorizontally) {
                                time.placeRelative(
                                    x = layoutWidth - time.width,
                                    y = messageMeasurement.size.height - time.height
                                )
                            } else {
                                time.placeRelative(
                                    x = layoutWidth - time.width,
                                    y = layoutHeight - time.height
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of this combines into this UI:

[image: UI]

Layout inspector doesn't show any unnecessary recompositions, DB query looks OK, custom layout doesn't seem to do a lot of heavy calculations, `svg` or `png` chat background doesn't seem to make statistical difference. The only statistical difference I've noticed came from the removal of a shadow on a custom concave shape.

**Am I missing something?** Is shadow really the culprit? If it is, why? How can one improve its performance?

If you've read this giant post, thank you. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: Did you check the layout inspector for unnecessary recompositions?

Comment: Yes.
`Layout inspector doesn't show any unnecessary recompositions`

Comment: Quite late to maybe help in any way, but curious to hear if you figure out what the issue was. There have been many reports on just poor performance on compose since the team is not focusing on that part yet. If you have not gotten anywhere with it still, I would suggest doing 50/50 debugging, and start by simplifying all your testable points; instead of a complex UI, make a very basic one with just text. Instead of a complex query object, just make a basic one for plain text, and slowly make them complex on every test until you find the big culprit.

Comment: PS: Also take under consideration that, like I said, the platform itself is just performing poorly if you end up not being able to single out one or two undeniable culprits.

Comment: I think I was doing exactly like you suggested. Take a look at the results table - I juggled possible culprits like crazy, but even "No DB, trivial UI" result is half a frame late half of the time. I searched online for Compose performance evaluation, and as far as I can see no one got even close to this bad of a result. Surely I messed something up?